# pc automatically turns on when plugged in

Tags: windows-10, motherboard, power-supply

Hello everyone I have some questions maybe you can help me with some advise on what I should do,, yesterday I have encountered a problem on my pc, My pc won't turn on immediately after shutdown so I tried searching for solutions online and what I found is to set the settings in bios which is to power on the computer when ac is connected/detected, in which case my pc will turn on automatically without pressing the power button, the question is,
is that harmful to my computer?

Answer (score 0):

No, its the same as pressing the power button. The purpose is for computers that must be turned on, like servers. If there is a power outage, when it ends, the computer goes back to doing it's job.

However this happens when the power goes off and then comes back. Computers are never completely turned off while powered. There are minimal circuits so it can wake or turn on if something happens like pressing the on button.

Comment: so its the same, okay thank you so much! one last thing after i set that settings in bios my keyboard is not functioning when booting up